# Return value from method (in order to use that value in other methods inside the same Class)

Tags: java, methods, return-value

```
    public void run() {
    moveTest();

   }

    private int moveTest() {
       while (frontIsClear()) {
        move();
        for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++);

       }

   }
```

There is the code, I want to basically count the loop (in order to find the middle point of an straight line, and then store the count into an ' int ' and than use that int (value) in another private method (or public if it needs to).

Thanks in advance hope you guys can understand my point ^^

Comment: What do you mean by "_count the loop_"?

Comment: The question appears to be off-topic, because questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Your loop condition is probably wrong, because there will be 0 iterations. You can use return keyword to return some value and then use it in another method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and strange, but I thing you can just create a private field in a class, return the result of method moveTest in it, and then use it in another method...
Like:

```
private int count = 0;
public void run() {
    count = moveTest();

    // use 'count'variable
}
private void someMethodUsingCountVariable() {
    int a = count;    
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is just trying to find out how to `return` a value from a method, so no field needed.